# Python (Maya) pass flags as variables

Tags: python, maya

I'm trying to run a command, with the specific flags dependant on which options I've selected in the UI. Specifically, this is for Maya, and I am trying to create a new attribute on a selected object. The problem is, depending on the type of attribute I want to create, I'll have different flags, and I'm not sure how to pass these flags to the command itself. here is the relevant code I'm having issues with

```
TYPENum= #gets value from Radio button group
if TYPENum==1:
    TYPE='at="enum", en="Off:On"'
elif TYPENum==2:
    TYPE='at="float", min=0, max=1'

cmds.addAttr(selectedObject, ln="AttrNameTextField", TYPE, k=True")
```

I would hope TYPE would plug in the at flag (attrbute type) as well as ether the en flag (enum names), or the min and max flags. Unfortunately, it's not recognizing the variable as flags,and returns a "SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg" error. There has got to be a way to build the command and then run it, but it's been a long while since I've coded any UI items, and I'm drawing a blank.

Thanks for your time.

PS: I haven't gotten that far, but I suspect the min/max values won't be recognized as integers. If you have a suggestion to resolve that, it would help the next potential hurdle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way to pass flags to a maya command is to use python's built-in **args syntax:

```
mesh_options = {'type':'mesh', 'long':True } 
meshes = cmds.ls(**mesh_options)
```

is equivalent to

```
cmds.ls(long=True, type='mesh')
```

In you case you want something like

```
opts = {"ln":"AttrNameTextField","k":True}
if typenum == 1:
   opts["at"] = "enum"
   opts["en"] = "Off:On"
else:
   opts["at"] = "float"
   opts["min"] = 0
   opts["max"] = 1
cmds.addAttr(selectedObject, **opts)
```

Comment: Ah, so using a dictionary rather than a list or string to define the flags, then the ** to call them. Thank you. That also solves the concern about integers I hadn't gotten to as well.